# Replacing rows in R

Tags: r, comments, rscript

In R am reading a file with comments as csv using

```
read.data.raw = read.csv(inputfile, sep='\t', header=F, comment.char='')
```

The file looks like this:

```
#comment line 1
data 1<tab>x<tab>y
#comment line 2
data 2<tab>x<tab>y
data 3<tab>x<tab>y
```

Now I extract the uncommented lines using

```
comment_ind = grep( '^#.*', read.data.raw[[1]])
read.data = read.data.raw[-comment_ind,]
```

Which leaves me:

```
 data 1<tab>x<tab>y
 data 2<tab>x<tab>y
 data 3<tab>x<tab>y
```

I am modifying this data through some separate script which maintains the number of rows/cols and would like to put it back into the original read data (with the user comments) and return it to the user like this

```
#comment line 1
modified data 1<tab>x<tab>y
#comment line 2
modified data 2<tab>x<tab>y
modified data 3<tab>x<tab>y
```

Since the data I extracted in read.data preserves the row names row.names(read.data), I tried

```
original.read.data[as.numeric(row.names(read.data)),] = read.data
```

But that didn't work, and I got a bunch of NA/s

Any ideas?

Comment: How exactly did it change the data? If it turned factors into characters, or similar changes in data types, that would account for the NAs.

Comment: Also, you're going to get NAs after the comment line in any column if you force the column to be numeric. R wasn't really meant to read in comment data along with the data frame, though you could find ways around it. In any case, you'd have to be more specific about the type of data you read in and how you modified it

Comment: The data I'm reading in is a 5 column formatted data: Column 1-3(numeric) column 4-5 character strings
In most cases I am replacing values in specific cells of the data frame (example data[5,8]=NA) and sometimes replacing the whole column (example data[[3]]=1:100)
I forced R to read the comment data, because when I set comment.char to '#', I lost the comment lines. So by getting R to read it that way, I can extract the uncommented lines, leaving commented lines behind. At least that was my logic behind my choices

Comment: Why not edit your original question to include a fully reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
read.data.raw <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L),
   .Label = c("#comment line 1", "#comment line 2", "data 1", "data 2", 
   "data 3"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
   .Label = c("", "x"), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L,
   2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "y"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
   "V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

comment_ind = grep( '^#.*', read.data.raw[[1]])
read.data <- read.data.raw[-comment_ind,]
# modify V1
read.data$V1 <- gsub("data", "DATA", read.data$V1)
# rbind() and then order() comments into original places
new.data <- rbind(read.data.raw[comment_ind,], read.data)
new.data <- new.data[order(as.numeric(rownames(new.data))),]
```

Comment: Ah! Sorting by the row names, I didn't think of that! Works like a charm! THANKS!